# How to ignore a single string value in an unordered map/ map?

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-map

I have a program that takes in a text file of DNA strings, splits them into kmer substrings and counts how many times a unique substring pops up. My only issue is having it recognize a string value "N" and ignore it in the file... for example a text file like so:

3 3

ACNTG

ACTG

ACTG

would split the dna sequence into 3 kmers, hence the first integer. The issue is i want to ignore the N and move on without including the N in the unique string value. so the output would be...

ACT,CTG, TGA... and so on while ignoring the N value. here is the portion of my code that I believe that portion should be included into:

```
    #include <fstream>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <unordered_map>

       std::string kmer = "";

     std::unordered_map<std::string, int  > dna;
       for(int i = 0; i< s.length() ; ++i){
        int z= 0;
        kmer = s.substr(z,k);
        ++z;

        if (kmer.length() != k){
                    break;
              }

//DONT UNDERSTAND WHY THIS WOULDNT WORK
       if(!dna.find("N")) !=std::string::npos)){
        dna[kmer]++;
         }

     }



          for (std::unordered_map<std::string,int>::iterator it=dna.begin(); it!=dna.end(); ++it){


            std::cout << it->first << " " << it->second << std::endl;
        }



  f.close();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have a mistake in the line

```
if(!dna.find("N")) !=std::string::npos)){
```

You probably meant it to be

```
if(kmer.find('N') !=std::string::npos){
```

- The latter one (which I think is the one you meant), checks for the position of character `'N'` in the string `kmer` using [`std::string::find`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/). This makes logical sense (you're checking whether the kmer contains a faulty N), and the return value indeed can be compared to `std::string::npos`.
- The former one (asides from a typo of an extra `!` at the front which  Ap31 noticed), checks for the position of the string `"N"` in the `unordered_map` using [`std::unordered_map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/find/). This doesn't make logical sense (you're probably not working with 1-mers), and the return value cannot be compared to `std::string::npos`.

Comment: how did you even manage to parse that first `!` in the condition? :D +1
It puzzled me quite a bit. Also those strings are begging for some user-defined hash

Comment: @Ap31 I just now got the point you made. Thanks! Until you raised it, I just didn't see it. Shortsightedness sometimes pays off :-)

Comment: well you were still able to give a correct answer, while I couldn't even figure out what this expression supposed to mean. I have to say though that brackets still don't quite add up in your current solution :D

Comment: @Ap31 You're right again, thanks! Corrected. Also tried to build it this time, but then it turned out that the entire is outside a function (there's no `main`).